# With Julia, is there a way to create a test/temporary/throwaway environement?

Tags: testing, package, julia

I would like to test the installation of a certain combination of packages without polluting my primary environment and without needing to create a folder. Is there a way to do this interactively/in the REPL?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For this specific purpose, there is also

```
(@v1.5) pkg> activate --temp
 Activating new environment at `/tmp/jl_r7woaE/Project.toml`
```

Comment: Is there a way to make `temp` inherit another environment and start from there?

Comment: @Royi They have been thinking about [subprojects](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/issues/1233) for quite a time, but I think not finalized them yet.

Comment: Is there a way to have it manually (In Julia). Namely copying the content of the `Project.toml` of a different project into the `temp` and then instantiate it?

Comment: I don't know whether that could work easily, maybe ask on Slack or make an issue. But wouldn't just using a Git branch work for that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, navigate to into a specific folder (this will be where the throw away env. files are) and then run `activate .` in the package manager.